# Can we find an explicit solution for $x$ in $\cos \left( a x\right) +2 \cos \left(b x\right)=0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

I have this equation
$$\cos \left( a x\right)   +2 \cos  \left(b x\right)=0$$
with ${a,b,x}>0$ and all reals. Then, is it possible to find an explicit solution for $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: the sum-to-product for cosine won't work (at least not immediately) because of the $2$ in front of the second term on the left.

Comment: If $t = \cos(x)$, I am unaware of any formula for $\cos(ax)$ in terms of $t$, for any real $a$.  The closest that I can come to an approach is [taylor series - cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions).

Comment: @coffeemath That is true, without the coefficient $2$, there is a solution.

Comment: You can reason that if $\cos(cx) = 2\cos(bx)$ then $cx = (\pi - ax)$.  This leads to $$\frac{\cos(\pi - ax)}{\cos(bx)} = 2$$ which seems to uniquely define $x$ but not in any *nice* manner.  Still, the same could be said for the inverse trig functions, when they were first originated.

Comment: one set of solutions can be determined when both cosines are zero

Comment: @Vasya +1: good point, my last comment overlooked that idea.